# Formatar String para "00:00:00"

Tags: java, formatação

Preciso que essa string saia no formato 00:00:00 atualmente ela sai: 5:4:1 por exemplo, oque fiz foi fazer varios ifs, porem é pouco eficiente, e tambem ele não formata quando os 3 estão abaixo de 10:

```
    long diffSeconds2 = long_hours / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes2 = long_hours / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours2 = long_hours / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;


    if (long_hours > 0) {
        if(diffSeconds2<10){
            str_testing = diffHours2 + ":" + diffMinutes2 + ":0" +diffSeconds2;

        }else if(diffMinutes2<10){
            str_testing = diffHours2 + ":0" + diffMinutes2 + ":" +diffSeconds2;
        }else if(diffHours2<10){
            str_testing = "0" + diffHours2 + ":" + diffMinutes2 + ":" +diffSeconds2;
        }
        //e se for os 3 abaixo de 10 teria que ficar: 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que seria mais fácil colocar um formatador para String dessa forma:

```
String hora = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", diffHours2, diffMinutes2, diffSeconds2);
```

Estou dizendo que o valor tem que ter 2 dígitos, logo se houver apenas 1 dígito ele vai completar com 0's à esquerda. Veja no [ideone](https://ideone.com/isfnfN).

Mas não me pareceu apresentar o resultado correto, então uma outra alternativa mais fácil é a seguinte:

```
long yourmilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");    
Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Dessa forma não precisa fazer nenhuma conta, veja no [ideone](https://ideone.com/imVeoX) (

Referência: [How to transform currentTimeMillis to a readable date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364383/how-to-transform-currenttimemillis-to-a-readable-date-format).

Comment: Isso que estava procurando, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

A logica que está a utilizar não está certa pois testa cada parcela do tempo em exclusão. Testa se os segundos são menor que `10` para por o `"0"` mas se for o caso já não vê os restantes, pois esses estão em `else if`.

Pode corrigir e utilizar operadores ternários para compactar um pouco o código:

```
str_testing = (diffHours2<10? "0":"") + diffHours2 + ":" + 
              (diffMinutes2<10 ? "0":"") + diffMinutes2 + ":" + 
              (diffSeconds2<10 ? "0":"") + diffSeconds2;
```

Assim cada parte é analisada em separado das outras e apenas mete o `"0"` correspondente caso seja inferior a `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Usando o `Formatter` ou `String.format` e assumindo que `long_horas` é o tempo em milissegundos:

```
String horas = String.format("%tT", long_horas);
```

bem simples já que `%tT` equivale a `%tH:%tM:%tS`, ou seja, hora, minutos e segundos com duas casas do argumento passado em millisegundos.

Nota: esses métodos, como tambem o `new Date` interpretam o tempo como milissegundos a partir de 1 Janeiro 1970 0:00 (GMT) e portanto podem ocorrer problemas em relação à horário de verão (para intervalos mais longos) e semelhantes...